# jQuery add index numbering to a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, attr

I have a lot of links on my website, all with the class "portfolio-click". I now want to add a "index number" to them all, so it would look something like:

```
<a class="portfolio-click" index_number="1">...</a>
<a class="portfolio-click" index_number="2">...</a>
```

Is there an easy way to make jQuery do this, so i can move around the links without interfering with the index order?

I tried:

```
    $( ".portfolio-click" ).attr( "index_number", function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < max_portfolio_number; i++) {
        return i;
    }
  });
```

but that did not work.

Comment: `$( ".portfolio-click" )` return an array of `div`s, you have to use `.each();`

Comment: Why do not you doing it whenever you are generating the <a> tag. If you fixed number of <a> then give index manually otherwise make counter and add this to index through a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var i = 0;
$(".portfolio-click").each(function(){
    $(this).attr('index_number', i++);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you'd need it, but using a valid data attribute you could do this :

```
$( ".portfolio-click" ).attr( "data-index", function(i) {
    return i;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/V3C9C/)

You can always access elements by index with jQuery methods, as in

```
$( ".portfolio-click" ).eq(4); // gets the fifth (zero based)
```

so you don't need an attribute for that ?

Comment: Can you explain please, why "function(i) {
    return i;}" and not just "i"?

Comment: It's a callback, whatever is returned is set as the value of the attribute, and the first argument is the index, as in `i`

Comment: It's because I have a portfolio, and i wan't to remove the "next" arrow when the last index-number is reached ;) If you want to check it out:

http://hersing.dk/canvas/jq4/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.each()`

```
$(".portfolio-click" ).each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr("index-number",i);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [.attr( attributeName, value )](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2)

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/H98YU/)</kbd>

```
$( ".portfolio-click" ).attr( "index_number", function(i) {
    return ++i; //index starts from so add 1 to it before return
});
```

---

Better use .data for custom attribute

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/H98YU/3)</kbd>

```
$(".portfolio-click").attr("data-index_number", function (i) {
    return ++i;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `.each()` function:

```
$('a.portfolio-click').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr("index-number",i);
});
```

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/rSGML/1/